# Called this method in the constructor, but nothing happens?

Tags: java, methods

I wanna call this method in the constructor so my program can adjust its text fields according to the sizes and positions of jTable. but when I call this method in the constructor , nothing happens. can someone tell me how to make this work when the program starts?

also I wanna call this method whenever user try to resize the jTable's columns. How can I do that?

```
private void setTextFields() {
    try {
        cpono.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), cpono.getSize().height);
        cicode.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), cicode.getSize().height);
        cdesc.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), cdesc.getSize().height);
        cum.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), cum.getSize().height);
        ccost.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), ccost.getSize().height);
        crqty.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), crqty.getSize().height);
        cdisrate.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), cdisrate.getSize().height);
        csubtot.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), csubtot.getSize().height);
        cdis.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), cdis.getSize().height);
        ctot.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), ctot.getSize().height);
        ccomments.setSize(grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth(), ccomments.getSize().height);

        cicode.setLocation((int) (cpono.getLocation().getX() + cpono.getSize().getWidth()), (int) cicode.getLocation().getY());
        cdesc.setLocation((int) (cicode.getLocation().getX() + cicode.getSize().getWidth()), (int) cicode.getLocation().getY());
        cum.setLocation((int) (cdesc.getLocation().getX() + cdesc.getSize().getWidth()), (int) cum.getLocation().getY());
        ccost.setLocation((int) (cum.getLocation().getX() + cum.getSize().getWidth()), (int) ccost.getLocation().getY());
        crqty.setLocation((int) (ccost.getLocation().getX() + ccost.getSize().getWidth()), (int) crqty.getLocation().getY());
        cdisrate.setLocation((int) (crqty.getLocation().getX() + crqty.getSize().getWidth()), (int) cdisrate.getLocation().getY());
        csubtot.setLocation((int) (cdisrate.getLocation().getX() + cdisrate.getSize().getWidth()), (int) csubtot.getLocation().getY());
        cdis.setLocation((int) (csubtot.getLocation().getX() + csubtot.getSize().getWidth()), (int) cdis.getLocation().getY());
        ctot.setLocation((int) (cdis.getLocation().getX() + cdis.getSize().getWidth()), (int) ctot.getLocation().getY());
        ccomments.setLocation((int) (ctot.getLocation().getX() + ctot.getSize().getWidth()), (int) ccomments.getLocation().getY());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Error", 0);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code would be much more readable, if you replace commonly used expressions like grntable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getWidth() with variable

Comment: Wow, that's very readable. :-)

Comment: setTextFields looks like a method, not a constructor to me. What is calling this method? Also, AFAIR, you listen to events in the UI, like resizing and then call such methods.

Comment: @D_K OP says: "I want to call this method from the constructor".

Comment: sorry about that guys, but what I simply need is to call this method when my program starts. and grntable is a jTable. all other variable names are used for jTextFields

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thnx, ingore the first part of my comment :)

Comment: Shouldn't some kind of Layoutmanager take care of this all? Or is it too long ago, I worked with swing/awt?

Comment: Fildor. I already did that, but it doesn't work as I want, that is why I decided to do this by coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to call this method whenever your table's columns resize,
first of all add the ColumnModeListener to your JTable (say jtable) :

```
jtable.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener()
```

then call your desired method (setTextFields) in the columnMarginChanged() method.
[take a look at this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableColumnModelListener.html)
and for the first part of your question please show what's before the snippet you've shown here?